# Opening a vector graphics file

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector-graphics, adobe-fireworks

I obtained a free graphic from [link text](http://all-free-download.com/graphic/vector-file/vector-icon/household_appliances_telephone_icon_vector_material_1960.html)

and when I open it in photoshop 7, or fireworks 8 the image comes up, but I can't select the individual image I want (the telephone) for example.  I'm not much of a graphics designer, and just hack my way around things, so I may be completely off, but should I be able to open a vector file then select just one image to manipulate?  I want to create a transparent png of the telephone for example.  Am I supposed to import it some different way?  Ideally I'd like to use these vector images similar to the way photoshop uses "layers" where I can have one image as a layer and drag it around, copy it, etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: I down voted because this is not programming specific. Maybe you could try asking on Super User.  Hint: Adobe Illustrator.

Comment: thanks, but confused...new to this forum...whats the point of the "flags" I thought selecting "graphics", photoshop, fireworks, vector, etc. would place this post where needs to be so it didn't bug people who don't care about this topic?  Mr. Berna, thanks for being constructive enough to point me to Illustrator rather than just down voting without direction, like the previous voter.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What file type is your download?  If it's Adobe Illustrator, like Mr. Berna said, you need a program that can recognize and import .AI files.  The free Inkscape is one possibility.